# ¿expresión regular para validar el NIE en PYTHON?

Tags: python

Ahora mismo lo que tengo sirve para calcular la letra del DNI y devolver el valor completo. Pero necesito lo mismo para el NIE. ¿Sabéis como hacerlo? Gracias

```
def letra_DNI_NIE(num):
    return 'TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE'[num%23]
letra_DNI_S=input('Introduce tu nº de dni:')
print('Tu dni completo es',num,letra)
```

Comment: Fonss_87, sería bueno que expliques que es el NIE para los que no lo sabemos. Te comento que lo ideal es que pongas el código de lo que llevas avanzado con eso del NIE, no que lo pidas explícitamente.

Comment: El NIE es el número de identificación para extranjeros en España. 
Tengo que introducir un valor de 8 dígitos y este me tiene que devolver una letra. La letra se calcula con el string 'TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE' dividiendo el número de DNI entre 23 y obtengo el residuo(una de las letras del string) 
Ahora bien, En el caso que el NIE empiece por X, se sustituye la X por 0, si el NIE empieza por Y, se
sustituye la letra Y por el número 1, si el NIE empieza por Z, se sustituye la letra Z por el
número 2 y se realiza el mismo cálculo.  
Ejemplo: si introduzco 'X2345678' 
'X1234567L'

Comment: Un comentario sobre terminología. Lo que buscas no es una expresión regular, sino la fórmula que te permite obtener la letra de verificación. Esto no puede hacerse con una expresión regular. Con la expresión regular puedes validar que cumple con la estructura esperada (que tiene dígitos y letras en ciertas posiciones), pero no que la letra sea la correcta.

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de que tuvieras este tipo de NIE `NIE_ejemplo = 'X 1234567-P'` podrías hace esto:

```
import re

def nie_validator():
    NIE_ejemplo = str(input())
    try:
        re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]\s\d{7}-[a-zA-Z]$', NIE_ejemplo)[0]
    except IndexError:
        print('Por favor introduzca su NIE de forma correcta')
```

Basicamente intentamos buscar la expresión primera en el string después del regex y si no la encontramos, porque no se han cumplido las condiciones, se mostrará el except.

### Desglose de la expresión regular

`'^[a-zA-Z]\s\d{7}-[a-zA-Z]$'`

- `^[a-zA-Z]`: El primer caracter tiene que ser una letra
- `\s`: el segundo caracter tiene que se un espacio
- `\d{7}`: los siguientes 7 carácteres tienen que ser números
- `-`: el siguiente caracter tiene que ser un guión
- `[a-zA-Z]$`: tiene que acabar por una letra

Comment: El NIE es el número de identificación para extranjeros en España. 
Tengo que introducir un valor de 8 dígitos y este me tiene que devolver una letra. La letra se calcula con el string 'TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE' dividiendo el número de DNI entre 23 y obtengo el residuo(una de las letras del string) 
Ahora bien, En el caso que el NIE empiece por X, se sustituye la X por 0, si el NIE empieza por Y, se
sustituye la letra Y por el número 1, si el NIE empieza por Z, se sustituye la letra Z por el
número 2 y se realiza el mismo cálculo.  
Ejemplo: si introduzco 'X2345678' 
'X1234567L'